# What is the maximum length for clientUserId

Tags: docusignapi

What is the maximum length for clientUserId?

https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/ does not say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximum length of clientUserId is 100

You can specify a clientUserId greater than 100 but Docusign will only consider upto 100 characters and ignore the remaining part.